# Keep value of variable in class, if no value supplied

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have several data classes that have 3 or 4 variables. These variables are then compared against a user imported file, to determine how long the process can continue.

Depending on the source of the data, some of the variables can be missing from the imported file. Currently, if this occurs, the variables are set to `0.0` as the default (not my code), which screws up the calculations.

Is there a way to ensure that the data class keeps an existing variable value if the set of variables being passed in is missing the value?

As an example, I have the following data class:

```py
@dataclass
class Machine_temps:
    machine: str
    machine_part_1: str
    machine_temp: float = 0.0
```

I also have the following import file code:

```py
for row in csv_reader:
    machine = row[0]
    machine_temp_part_1 = row[1]
    machine_temp = float(row[2])
    m = Machine_temps(machine, machine_temp_part_1, machine_temp)
return m
```

The CSV file would be as follows:

```
Fl_1_Pos_1, Part_2, 18.0

Fl_1_Pos_1, Part_3, 18.0

Fl_1_Pos_1, Part_3,

Fl_2_Pos_1, Part_1, 10.2
```

In the above, the temperature is missing from the 3rd row. I would need the data to revert to the expected value of `18.0`. However, it reverts gets set to `0.0`, which would not be correct.

Comment: You're creating new instance of class in your code and I see no other instances of this class which contains already existing values.

Comment: Why not set a default value in the class or use a conditional statement to check if missing and set it to default.

Comment: @OlvinRoght there is more additional code for creating the original values. The issue is that when a file has a blank, it overwrites the original values with the default value of 0.00, which is not correct.

Comment: @MichealN.D how would I go about doing this?

Comment: @OlvinRoght not sure I understand your solution. I believe that I would need to check the value of the machine, and pull its temp from the original data, but not sure how that is possible.

Comment: @Clauric, actually that's what this small sample of code does. If `value` is *True* (read: [Truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)) it won't be changed, otherwise it will be replaced with `new_value`.

Comment: @Clauric, sorry there was my mistake in code, correct version: `value = value or new_value`.

Comment: Set the defaults value in the class init dunder method parameters or in the method that recieves the data. Another way if using a boolean to check if its empty then set it as default. For me to assist properly i need u to update your code in the question.